# Getting error CS1061 with navigation property in a partialview (mvc razor entity framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, ienumerable

Hi i'm getting error CS1061 when calling a partialview from a controller.
I'm using a solution with separate projects containing Mvc and EF.

My model are a **Menu** and **MenuItem** entities (abreviated from EF):

```
public partial class Menu : EntityObject
{
#region Propiedades primitivas
public global::System.Int32 Id
public global::System.String Name
#region Propiedades de navegación
[EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("DAL_EF_Model", "MenuMenuItem", "MenuItem")]
    public EntityCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems
```

...

```
public partial class MenuItem : EntityObject
{
#region Propiedades primitivas
public global::System.Int32 Id
public global::System.String Name
public global::System.String ActionName
public global::System.String ControllerName
public global::System.String Url
```

...

The Controller is:
...

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult MenuLayout(string name)
    {
        if (db.Menus.Count<Menu>() > 0 &&
            db.MenuItems.Count<MenuItem>() > 0)
        {
            //var todos = new MenuV();
            //todos = db.Menus.ToList();
            List<Menu> otros = db.Menus.ToList();
            foreach (var opcion in db.Menus)
            {
                List<Menu> menu = db.Menus
                    .Include("MenuItems")
                    .ToList();
                    //.Single<Menu>(m => m.Name == opcion.Name);
                return PartialView("_MenuLayout", menu);
            }
            return PartialView("_MenuLayout", null);
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_MenuLayout", null);
        }
    }
```

...

And the partialview _MenuLayout.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<DAL_EF.Menu>
<div id="accordion">
 <div><h3><a href="#"> ERP </a></h3>
   @{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        <div><ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems)
        {
            <li id="@item.Name">@Html.ActionLink(
            @item.Name,
            @item.ActionName,
            @item.ControllerName)</li>
        }
        </ul></div>
    }
}
 </div> 
</div>
```

The error occurs in the

```
IEnumerable<DAL_EF.Menu>
```

If i use

```
.Single<Menu>
```

from controller and the partialview receives

```
 DAL_EF.Menu
```

it works fine.

The complete error message is:

```
    {"_MenuLayout.cshtml(21): error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DAL_EF.Menu>' no contiene una definición de 'MenuItems' ni se encontró ningún método de extensión 'MenuItems' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<DAL_EF.Menu>' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@model IEnumerable<DAL_EF.Menu>
```

This specifies that your model is of type IEnumerable< DAF_EL.Menu >. However, you are using the model as if it were of type DAL_EF.Menu.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems)
```

As the error message says, IEnumerable< DAL_EF.Menu > (which is what your Model is) doesn't have a property called MenuItems, because it's a whole bunch of Menus, not just a single Menu.

You probably want something like this, to loop through each Menu in your model, and then loop through each MenuItem in each menu.

```
@foreach (Menu menu in Model)
{
    @foreach(var item in menu.MenuItems)
    {
        .. do your stuff ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Marty, you could not be more right ... my confusion came because I thought the error was in becoming @model and not within the logic of the view. Thank you very much!